# Azure database latency killing app

Tags: database, performance, azure, latency

I've done a lot of reading about latency of azure database on stackoverflow and various blogs around the web.  I cannot figure out what is going on, however, with the high latency I'm experiencing between my azure website and azure database.

I notice my app was running very slow so I clocked the time to run a query (the query themselves take ~0ms for the db to execute).  On average, it is taking 175ms to execute a query and get a response from the db.  If I do 10 queries in a single page load, that 1.75 seconds just in latency!  I get much better performance than that from a budget host running Mysql.

Any advice on how to address this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like my db is not in the same region as my website.  Plan B: Change the region of one of those.

Comment: You should really put this in an *answer* vs a *comment*.

Comment: Well, you have two possibilities. First, move the website and the database into the same region. Second, perform less queries - use caching and merge smaller operations into larger ones where applicable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the database was in a different region than my website.  Moving it into the same datacenter took the latency down from ~175ms to ~30ms.